# appcompat-v7:25.2.0 conflicts with play-services:10.2.1

Tags: android, gradle, google-play-services, android-support-library

I am working on a new app. Presently I am trying to add dependency

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1'
```

When I do I get a gradle compile error on `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'` saying:

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 25.2.0, 24.0.0. Examples include
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.2.0 and
>   com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:24.0.0 less... (⌘F1) There are some
>   combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are
>   incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is
>   compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not
>   the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your
>   targetSdkVersion.)

Any ideas how to best resolve this issue?

Gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "appIdhere"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        resValue "string", "authority", "${applicationId}"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    provided "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.8"
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Show the gradle file. Do you have `com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:24.0.0`?

Comment: Please read this https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split  You will likely never use every google play service in one app

Comment: I just saw your comment. Thanks. For the life of me I thought I was just using `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.1'`. My head is not focussing today. Thanks, cricket.

Comment: No worries. Though, I would recommend Firebase messaging instead

Comment: I am using it for the GcmNetworkManager

Answer (score 5):

you -> Compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:#version'

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was it for me. I was looking to exclude a dependency instead. :)  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.3.1'

Answer (score 4):

Update your build.gradle file with the following:

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'

Comment: I did that. Then I cleaned and rebuilt. Still nothing.

Comment: I assume you are updating the module level build.gradle and have also tried restarting the Android Studio. If the error persists paste the updated gradle file. My error was resolved when I updated module level build.gradle file with the correct appcompat lib  that was compatible with buildtoolversion.

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'

Answer (score 1):

> You should replace the following line in your build.gradle file:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1'
```

> with these lines

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:10.2.1'
```

> you may also add these lines as per your requirement

```
//for Google+
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:10.2.1'
//for Google Account Login
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.1'
```

> For Reference you must follow 
>   [https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup]

Answer (score 1):

Later answer but hope it helps someone who has similar problem.

Firstly, "Don't use the combined play-services target. It brings in dozens of libraries, bloating your application. Instead, specify only the specific Google Play services APIs your app uses.". Here is play-services module list for each API: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split

Your problem, there is conflicted of `com.android.support` library version in `play-services` library with `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1`. To fix this, just modify

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1' 
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1' 
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.2.1'
```

to

```
compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.2.1') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
```